Sum of modular multiplicative units
Given the sum
$$g(n)=\sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_n}a$$
where $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_n$ is the multiplicative modular unit group.
I want to know:

is there some standard function or symbol representing it?
any remarkable properties
any relations with arithmetic functions or Dirichlet convolutions

Particularly I have found that this number is always a multiple of $n$ and $\phi(n)$, euler's totient function.
This is exactly:
$$g(n) = \sum_{a \in  \mathbb{Z}^{*}_n}a=\frac{ \phi(n)n}{2}$$
Examples:
if  $n=12$:
$$g(12) = 1+5+7+11 = 4*12/2 = 24$$
if  $n=7$, this is the sum of the first 6 positive integers:
$$g(7) = 1+2+...+6 = 6*7/2 = 21$$

Not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking for a proof that $g(n)=\frac {n\varphi(n)}2$?

@lulu Not really, it seems not difficult to prove. Im looking for some results using it or how it can be related to other functions

I agree, it's easy to prove.  But...you already have the function described in terms of familiar arithmetic functions.  What more do you want?

@lulu Anything more, it seems an interesting fact and I cant recall it in the number theory book I've read. So it seems strange havent heard about. Also I want to go in the direction to characterize a sum of integers below a given one, in terms of arithmetic functions like this, like the sum of divisors. For primes I have it.

A more general formula is $\sum_{a \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}n}f(a)=\sum{d|n}\mu(d)\cdot \sum_{l=1}^{n/d}f\left(l\cdot d\right)$ where $\mu$ is the Mobius function. Is it helpfull for you?

@zhrd yes, nice formula. I also found that its not a multiplicative function

The idea is like

If $(a,n)=1$, so is $(-a,n)$. Therefore if $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, so is $n-a$, and they will always have a sum of $n$.
$\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ has exactly $\phi(n)$ elements by definition.


Duplicate Please do not post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
